# Snowflake SQL: regex_replace for CamelCase strings

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I need to transform the following string as follows:

Before:
`6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141`

After:
`6621 Lake Valley Dr`

Additional ways the data comes in:
`143 Evergreen Forest Court` (this one is fine as is)

Need to extract address only for these as well:

1. `326 Hambrick Park Fayetteville, GA 30215`
2. `RE: Owner's Policy - 112 Shagbark Ln Mooresville, NC 28115`
3. `RE: Owner's Policy - 540 Clearbrook Dr Covington, GA 30016`
4. `Closed 9/1/21 4421 Home Stakes Dr Parkton, NC 28371`
5. `RP 9/16- 352 Hampton St Elloree, SC 29047`
6. `RP: 9/15- 124 Lake Grove Rd Simpsonville, SC 29681`
7. `FHA 3/2/22- 6083 Holiday Blvd Forest Park, GA 30297`
8. `RD 10/1/21 Roxanne Sellers- 311 Woodbrook Ln Marietta, GA 30068`
9. `4104 Flat Trl- Ricardo Reeder`

How can I accomplish this using Snowflake SQL? I'm assuming regex_replace is in order? Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you add more examples of the transformation you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you only give us one example, we can only solve for that example:

```sql
select regexp_replace(x, '(.*[a-z])([A-Z].*)', '\\1')
from (select '6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141' x)
```

If you need help with a more general case, please start a new question with more sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: Good call, Felipe! Here's some other examples of how the inputs look:

`1306 Eddie Craig Ct McDonough, GA 30252`

`143 Evergreen Forest Court` (this one is fine as is). 

I made the edits above

Comment: Ok your solution helped with one of my issues, but doesn't work for the strings that look like this: `7401 Bosson St SW Concord, NC 28025`

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with the help of a capture group:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '6621 Lake Valley DrMemphis, TN 38141' AS address
)

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(address, '(\d+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*).*', '\1') AS address_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The above working demo is for Postgres, not Snowflake.  You might have to use `$1` instead of `\1` for the first capture group, but the rest should run unaltered.

Comment: That resulted in: `Invalid regular expression: '(d+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*).*', no argument for repetition operator: ?`

I removed the ? and it didn't result in my desired output (just gave me my original string back)

Comment: Try the updated version.

Comment: Still gave me my original string back. Also tried it with $1 and same thing :/